# Smallest topology containing a basis $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $X$ be a topological basis with a basis $\mathcal{B}$ generating the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Prove that $\mathcal{T}$ is the smallest topology on $X$ which contains $\mathcal{B}$.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $\mathcal{T}'$ be a topology on $X$ which contains $\mathcal{B}$. We must show that $\mathcal{T}' \supset \mathcal{T}$. Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$. Then, by definition of the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$, for every $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset \mathcal{B}$. Therefore, $U \subset \bigcup\limits_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B$. As $\mathcal{T}' \supset \mathcal{B}$, for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $B \in \mathcal{T}'$, and since $\mathcal{T}'$ is a topology and hence closed under unions, we have $U = \bigcup\limits_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B \in \mathcal{T}'$. Therefore, $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$, so $\mathcal{T}$ is the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B}'$.

How does this look? Do I need to prove that a "smallest topology on $X$" exists, or have I done that by using this definition that $\mathcal{T}$ is coarser than any other topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: "Do I need to prove that a "smallest topology on X" exists." I don't understand this. Didn't you show that T is the smallest topology on X containing B?

Comment: @PNDas I was wondering whether I need to start the proof out with "let $\mathcal{T}_L$ be the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B}$," prove that such a topology exists (I assume by taking the intersection of all topologies on $X$ containing $\mathcal{T}$ and proving that's a topology) and then showing $\mathcal{T}_L \subset \mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}_L$.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct but could be faster by avoiding going down to the elements of the space.

Let $U$ be an open set of $\cal T$. By definition of a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)), $U$ is the union of some subfamily of $\cal B$. Let now $\cal T'$ be a topology containing $\cal B$. Since a topology is closed under union, $\cal T'$ contains $U$. It follows that $\cal T$ is contained in $\cal T'$ and hence $\cal T$ is the smallest topology containing $\cal B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\tau_{\mathcal{B}} = \bigcap_{S \in \scr{S}}S$

Where, $\scr{S} =\{\tau : \mathcal{B} \subset \tau\}$

i.e $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the intersection of all topologies on $X$ containing the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Note :

1. Intersection of topologies of $X$ is again a topology on on  $X$.
2. The intersection makes sense as there is always a topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B} $ namely the discrete topology [$\tau_{dis}={\scr{P}}(X) $]

3)Intersection forces $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ to be the smallest topology with that property.

Comment: It makes sense to me that this is the case, but I'm wondering whether this is required by the problem statement.